# Sympy series expansion with numerical integration

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-integration

I want to make a series expansion for a function `F(e,Eo)` up to a certain power of `e` and integrate over the `Eo` variable numerically.
What I thought was using SymPy to make the power series in `e`, and then use MPMath for the numerical integration over `Eo`.

Below is an example code. I receive the message that it can not create mpf from the expression. I guess the problem has to do with the fact that with the series from SymPy has an `O(e**5)` term at the end, and later that I want the numerical integration to show a function of `e` instead of a number.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from mpmath import *
e = sp.symbols('e')
Eo = sp.symbols('Eo')
expr = sp.sin(e-2*Eo).series(e, 0, 5)
F = lambda Eo : expr
I = quad(F, [0, 2*np.pi])
print(I)
```

It’s evident that I need a different approach, but I would still need the numerical integration for my actual code because it has much more complicated expressions that could not be integrated analytically.

Edit: I should have chosen a complex function of real variables for the example code, I am trying this (the expansion and integration) for functions such as:

```
expr = (cos(Eo) - e - I*sqrt(1 - e ** 2)*sin(Eo)) ** 2 * (cos(2*(Eo - e*sin(Eo))) + I*sin(2*(Eo - e*sin(Eo))))/(1 - e*cos(Eo)) ** 4
```

Comment: Sidenote 1: The line `F = lambda Eo : expr` will almost certainly not do what you want, as the `Eo` of the lambda expression is not the same as the one used in `expr`. You probably want to use something like `F = lambda x: expr.subs(Eo,x)` or SymPy’s `lambdify`.

Comment: Sidenote 2: Why is everybody using MPMath for all sorts of problems? It’s for arbitrary-precision math, which is all fine and proper but also something that most problems do not require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach similar to Wrzlprmft's answer but with a different way of handling coefficients, via SymPy's [polynomial module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html):

```
from sympy import sin, pi, symbols, Integral, Poly

def integrate_coeff(coeff):
    partial_integral = coeff.integrate((Eo, 0, 2*pi))
    return partial_integral.n() if partial_integral.has(Integral) else partial_integral

e,Eo = symbols("e Eo")
expr = sin(e-sin(2*Eo))  
degree = 5

coeffs = Poly(expr.series(e, 0, degree).removeO(), e).all_coeffs()
new_coeffs = map(integrate_coeff, coeffs)
print((Poly(new_coeffs, e).as_expr() + e**degree).series(e, 0, degree))
```

The main code is three lines: (1) extract coefficients of e up to given degree; (2) integrate each, numerically if we must; (3) print the result, presenting it as a series rather than a polynomial (hence the trick with adding e**degree, to make SymPy aware that the series continues). Output:

```
-6.81273574401304e-108 + 4.80787886126883*e + 3.40636787200652e-108*e**2 - 0.801313143544804*e**3 - 2.12897992000408e-109*e**4 + O(e**5)
```

Comment: Nice solution, but how could it be optimized so that it doesn't waste time computing the coefficients once the value seems small? like for the example function you use in the code, it makes the integration for the coefficients with results of the order e-100.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the numerical integration to show a function of e instead of a number.

This is fundamentally impossible.
Either your integration is analytical or numerical, and if it is numerical it will only handle and yield numbers for you (the words *numerical* and *number* are similar for a reason).

If you want to split the integration into numerical and analytical components, you have to do so yourself – or hope that SymPy automatically splits the integration as needed, [which it unfortunately is not yet capable of](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13371).
This is how I would do it (details are commented in the code):

```
from sympy import sin, pi, symbols, Integral
from itertools import islice

e,Eo = symbols("e Eo")
expr = sin(e-sin(2*Eo))

# Create a generator yielding the first five summands of the series.
# This avoids the O(e**5) term. 
series = islice(expr.series(e,0,None),5)

integral = 0
for power,summand in enumerate(series):
    # Remove the e from the expression
    Eo_part = summand/e**power
    # … and ensure that it worked:
    assert not Eo_part.has(e)

    # Integrate the Eo part:
    partial_integral = Eo_part.integrate((Eo,0,2*pi))

    # If the integral cannot be evaluated analytically, …
    if partial_integral.has(Integral):
        # … replace it by the numerical estimate:
        partial_integral = partial_integral.n()

    # Re-attach the e component and add it to the sum:
    integral += partial_integral*e**power
```

Note that I did not use NumPy or MPMath at all (though SymPy uses the latter under the hood for numerical estimates). Unless you really really know what you’re doing, mixing those two with SymPy is a bad idea as they are not even aware of SymPy expressions.

Comment: I would like to know what method does it use for the numerical estimate of .integrate().n().